# Partitioning a set with intersections

Tags: combinatorics

Imagine that we want to give an exam consisting of $m$ problems to $n$ students in such a way that every two sets of problems have one or zero problems in common. Is there a closed formula to compute the minimal number of problems $K_{m,n}$ we need for given $m$ and $n$?

After thinking about this for some time, I found what seems to me to be a way to calculate $n$ given $K$ and $m$: there are $\dfrac{K(K-1)}{2}$ pairs of problems and $\dfrac{m(m-1)}{2}$ pairs of problems in each set, and we can cover $n = \left \lfloor\dfrac{K(K-1)}{m(m-1)}\right \rfloor$ students with no two of them sharing more than one problem. If this is correct is there a way to obtain an exact value for $K$ from this equation?

Comment: The key words to search for are "combinatorial design": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_design

Comment: I note that your proposed question and your proposed answer don't match each other. Are you given $m$ and $n$ and trying to compute $K$, or given $K$ and $m$ and trying to compute $n$?

Comment: @GregMartin, I meant “an exact value for K” in the last sentence.